# What percent of the web's images have alt text?

Tags: accessibility, statistics

Web developers are strongly encouraged to add alt text (via the `<img>` tag's `alt="text here"` attribute) when adding images to webpages.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test)'s an example of alt text providing a description of the image in place of the image:

[image: When the image loads it has a girl in a jacket, when the image fails to load the text 'girl in jacket' is displayed in place of the image]

#### Question

Have any studies estimated what proportion of the images on the web have alt text? For example, is it closer to 90%, 50%, just 20%?

#### Background

I've been doing a little reading on accessibility and assistive technologies to better understand what developers can do to assist users. This is just a question that popped into my head, which I thought I should be able to answer, but couldn't.

Comment: This checklist contains a lot of items that developers can do to improve accessibility: https://www.a11yproject.com/checklist/

Answer (score 1):

A couple top hits [searching DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=accessibility+statistics+%22alternative+text%22) for:

> accessibility statistics "alternative text"

...recently report approx. **75% of "home pages" have alternative text** for images.

Sources provided by those sites:

https://webaim.org/projects/million/#alttext

> 23.2% of all home page images...had missing alternative text (not counting alt="").

https://www.levelaccess.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/SODAR-2021-Final-a11y.pdf

Comment: The alt attribute is allowed to be empty, but it is hard to know if it was left empty on purpose or if it was a CMS adding the attribute but the user left it empty because of a non-awareness of accessibility.